# Reuse the api response from server for later use

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a list of twitter account users.When user click on any particular user i call the twitter api to collect all tweets from server and store it in NSArray. suppose i have a 1000 of tweets and i don't want o call that api again and again then is there any best way to store that tweets so the next time when the same user click, then that tweets display directly without a api call. i want the solution without the use of database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need a launch session lifetime of the data (i.e. turn app off - data lost) and don't want to use database (not sure why, it's really easier with Core Data, even using in-memory storage - fast and convenient) you may create a singleton class to store the lists. That could be a dictionary with keys - user_id, values - arrays with tweets.

```
user_id -> [tweet1, tweet2]
```

You ask it for tweets for a user id, and it returns array or nil.

I'd suggest you to use Core Data. Using Core Data you could easily switch to file storage (SQLite or file) or to in-memory store. It handles all the stuff under the hood. But anyway - it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks MANIAK_dobrii. but if i use dicionary or singleton class it will take a memory till the application is running.

Comment: You've mentioned that you don't want to use a database. So how do you want to save data avoiding use of database? Sure you'll need that, and Core Data is the best solution then I believe. I use it in all my live apps (yepp they all require a good data storage) and that works fine. Note that Apple guys've spent a lot of time optimizing things for us, so take a look.

Comment: Ok Thanks, i will try o use core data. but can we do that thing using NSCache ?

Comment: Not sure about that, but, someone here should know.